# Copying comma delimited data

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, 32-bit, worksheet-function

I am copying several hundred rows of comma delimited data into Excel 2010 (32-Bit version).

Part of the data in some rows get separated into columns, e.g. (just an example - does not actually happen):

```
{1, "Hello", 8,"Bye"},
{2, "John", 9,"Joe"},
{3, "Hot", 10,"Cold"},
{4, "Bad", 11,"Good"},
{5, "Red", 12,"Blue"},
```

Gets copied as:

```
Column A                          Column B             
{1, "Hello", 8,"Bye"},
{2,                              "John", 9,"Joe"},
{3, "Hot", 10,"Cold"},
{4, "Bad",                       11,"Good"},
{5, "Red", 12,"Blue"},
```

The maximum row length I am copying is 235 and Excel should allow at least 255 characters.  I have read that Excel 2010 allows 32,767 characters per cell.

Does anyone know why some of the rows are getting separated in separate columns?

Here is an example of a row that Excel put into separate columns:

```
/* XXX */{"00000000000000000", XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX       , XX(XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX      ), XXXX , "X"   , XXXX       , X    , XXXXXX     , X          ,  XX, XXX, XXX, XXX    , XXXXXXXX, XXXXXXXX , XXXXXXXXXXX     , XXXXXXXXXXX   , "XXX" },
```

Here is an example of a row that Excel did not put into separate columns:

```
/* XXX */{"XXXXX X. XXXXXX*"  , XX.XXXXXXXXX            , XX(XXXXXXXXXXX            ), XXXX , ""     , XXX  , XX   , X     , X         ,  XX, XXX, XXX, XXX    , XXXXXXXX, XXXXXXXX, XXXXXXXXXXXXXX, XXXXXXXXXXXX  , ""             },
```

Comment: I think you are going to need to give the actual example where you replace any private data with something else.

Comment: Here's the Example:/* XXX */{"00000000000000000", XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX       , XX(XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX      ), XXXX , "X"   , XXXX   , X    , XXXXXX  , X          ,  XX, XXX, XXX, XXX    , XXXXXXXX, XXXXXXXX , XXXXXXXXXXX  , XXXXXXXXXXX , "XXX" },

Comment: Here's an Example that doesn't get separated: /* XXX */{"XXXXX X. XXXXXX*"  , XX.XXXXXXXXX            , XX(XXXXXXXXXXX            ), XXXX , ""     , XXX  , XX   , X     , X         ,  XX, XXX, XXX, XXX    , XXXXXXXX, XXXXXXXX, XXXXXXXXXXXXXX, XXXXXXXXXXXX  , ""             },

Comment: that pastes as the same text to me.

Comment: Try adding it up above as code rather than in these commnets.

Comment: Carter said "that pastes as the same text to me.".  Do you mean it didn't separate the first example when you pasted into Excel?

Comment: Are you using the 32-Bit or 64-Bit edition of Excel?

Answer (score 1):

I would use something like Notepad++ and its find and replace feature.
Replace the brackets with nothing and replace the commas with \t (using "Extended" Search Mode.  Then copy and paste

Comment: Ok...I didn't explain whether I wanted the data to get separated or not:). It might sound strange, but I don't want the data to get separate into separate columns.

Comment: gotcha, I guess it depends on where you are copying the data from i.e. HTML, Word, Text, etc.  There could be extra spaces or characters being added.

Comment: Notepad++ and Notepad give me the same results.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be something like a tab character is some of your data. Your options are either:

- deal with this before input to Excel, or
- deal with this in Excel.

For the former something like Notepad++ (or many other applications) should suit, as indicated by @xjx424 (to replace the control sequence having determined what that is).

For the latter (my preference), if `{1` etc is in A2, I'd put:

```
=TRIM(A2&B2)
```

in C2 and copy down to suit. Then select all, Copy, Paste Special, Values over the top and delete ColumnsA:B.

If getting split (sometimes) into more than two pieces this is easy to extend.

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks.  I didn't realize a tab would cause Excel to separate the text into different columns.